# Associate file type with Chrome Packaged App

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

Is there any way to associate some file types in you OS to Chrome Packaged App.
I mean if you open  file with  *.some  extension, it would open with my packaged app

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is, but it is currently only supported on ChromeOS. We have plans to bring this feature to Windows, Mac and Linux in the near future.

To create an association, use the [`file_handlers` attribute of the Chrome app manifest](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/file_handlers). For example, to make *.some files open with your packaged app:

```
"file_handlers": {
  "handler_name": {  # Can be anything
    "extensions": [
      "some"
    ],
    "title": "My application"  # Make this the same as your app title
  }
}
```

This will create a file association in ChromeOS. When we roll out support on other platforms, it will automatically create the file associations there and you won't have to make any changes.

Comment: It's great, thanks, Chrome Apps can be full  value desktop apps

Comment: Does anyone know when is it going to be available for other platforms (Linux)? It would be great to have applications like image viewer and video player inside Chrome browser. I would like to have only Chrome installed and have access to my favorite apps.

Comment: It will be available for Mac in Chrome 36 or 37 (I forget which). There are still plans to bring it to Windows and Linux but no concrete date.

Comment: It's october news that windows got support http://www.chromestory.com/2014/10/automatic-file-association-apps-chrome-takes-one-step-deep-windows-territory/, any idea if it got merged upstream and to which version? (I'm supposing 40 but need to test)

Comment: @ValerioColtrè: The change you mention is in Chrome 40, but it's very hard to get working. You need an app_shim executable (which is not currently distributed with Chrome; you would have to build it from the Chromium source), and also to turn on the --enable-apps-file-associations flag. Hopefully we can get the shim packaged with Chrome 41 so you will just need to turn on the flag.

Comment: Is this feature available now for all the platforms?